# Contacts sorting similar to viber iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, filtering

Im trying to filter my contacts similar to Viber iOS App. Listing out contacts by bifurcating into two categories which is "all" and "App users only" by switching segmented control.

While fetching the contact list, it is taking more time if the number of contacts are high.

Currently I am manually running a for-loop to fetch the contacts, please let me know if there is any other alternative to this.

```
`-(void)usersList:(NSMutableDictionary *) dictUsrs    
{
NSDictionary *contactDetails;
arrContactsUser = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arrContactsUser removeAllObjects];
NSArray *sorted = [[sectionForRecievedContacts allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    //             NSOrderedAscending, NSOrderedSame, NSOrderedDescending
    BOOL isPunct1 = [[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[(NSString*)obj1 characterAtIndex:0]] || [[NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[(NSString*)obj1 characterAtIndex:0]] || [[NSCharacterSet illegalCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[(NSString*)obj1 characterAtIndex:0]] ||
    [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[(NSString*)obj1 characterAtIndex:0]];
    BOOL isPunct2 = [[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[(NSString*)obj2 characterAtIndex:0]] || [[NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[(NSString*)obj2 characterAtIndex:0]] || [[NSCharacterSet illegalCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[(NSString*)obj2 characterAtIndex:0]]||
    [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[(NSString*)obj2 characterAtIndex:0]];

    if (isPunct1 && !isPunct2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else if (!isPunct1 && isPunct2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;

    return [(NSString*)obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
}];

for (int j=0; j<[[dictUsrs allKeys] count]; j++) {

    for (int i=0; i<[[dictUsrs valueForKey:[sorted objectAtIndex:j]] count]; i++) {

        contactDetails = [[dictUsrs valueForKey:[sorted objectAtIndex:j]] objectAtIndex:i];

        fetchCount++;

        if ([contactDetails objectForKey:@"status"] == nil) {
            NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j];
                           if (fetchCount < kFetchLimit) {
                                [self startStatusFetcher:contactDetails forIndexPath:path withTableView:tableViewIngIngUsers];
                    NSLog(@"Fetch for Cell For Row at IndexPath");
            }

        }
        if ([contactDetails objectForKey:@"registered"] != nil && [[contactDetails objectForKey:@"registered"] isEqualToString:@"yes"]) {
            [arrContactsUser addObject:contactDetails];

        }

    }

}
   [self.tableViewIngIngUsers reloadData];
```

}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

});`
```

dispatch queue given me temparary solution to avoid this long delay in fetching.

Answer (score 0):

fetch your contacts info in the other thread, or just delay call in the application did launch. So the data can be cached, when you want to use it, just read the cache one.

Comment: already im using threads to fetch contacts, & I solved it using dispatch queue but too i cant get similar UI like viber app